# OAuth returning no token evernote

Tags: php, oauth, sdk, cloud, evernote

Using the sample from the github (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/oauth/index.php):

Site loads to the authroization on evernote's site. I choose 1-year. Click authorize and get returned to my script as expected. However, I get two `errors`:

> Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php/src/Evernote/Auth/OauthHandler.php on line 71
>
> Undefined index: oauth_token in /home/ubuntu/workspace/webroot/a.php on line 29

Also on the echo: `Oauth Token`: (it's blank here).
Can't seem to figure out what is happening, this worked once before but is not working now. The only difference is, I requested to have my app moved to production. Would that disable my ability to use it on the sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i figured this out. I am currently using CakePHP3 framework. Even though I can access and retrieve information from Evernote, the oAuth system doesn't work. I created a separate php app for getting oAuth and it worked just fine. Will research more and if I find a solution to using CakePHP I'll post it here. If anyone else has a suggestion, please post it, but I am marking this as the answer.